# Spring Boot / JUnit 5 / Mockito - mocking dependencies in Test classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to write JUnit 5 tests for a Spring Boot API but running into problem with dependency injection in the Test class. I wish to test endpoints in the ProfileController, which has 3 dependencies: ProfileService, ProfileModelAssembler (to add REST-centric decorations to json response, e.g. "links") and ModelMapper. In my Test class, I have the following 3 annotated as shown:

```
@InjectMocks
ProfileController profileController;

@Mock
ProfileService profileService;

@Mock
ProfileModelAssembler profileModelAssembler;

@Mock
ModelMapper modelMapper;
```

When I try to run a test, it errors out instantiating the ProfileController due to unsatisfied dependency for the ProfileService ("No qualifying bean of type x.ProfileService available").

In my ProfileController, I have tried to @Autowire those fields directly (not recommended, I know):

```
@Autowired
private ProfileService profileService;
@Autowired
private ProfileModelAssembler profileModelAssembler;
@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;
```

as well as via constructor injection:

```
@Autowired
public ProfileController(ProfileService profileService, ProfileModelAssembler profileModelAssembler, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
    this.profileService = profileService;
    this.profileModelAssembler = profileModelAssembler;
    this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
}
```

Error is the same either way. Tutorials I have found for JUnit and Mockito are absolutely all over the place in approach, doing things radically different from one another. I know there are always multiple solutions to a problem, but I've been surprised at how little adherence to any sort of "preferred" practice there is. Any recommendations to eliminate this error or resources to which I could turn to learn JUnit/Mockito in a "simple" way for my relatively simple needs?

Comment: Please show your full test instead of random snippets. I suspect you are using `@SpringBootTest` to run your test but without seeing the test class this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Yes, `@Mock`/`@InjectMocks` is Mockito, whereas `@Autowired`/`@MockBean` is for Spring Boot based tests

Answer (score 3):

`@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations have nothing to do with Spring so it doesn't matter how you autowire the dependencies in the `ProfileController` class. From the error you got it looks like you are running the test with `@SpringBootTest` where the application context is started so you would need to use the `@MockBean` annotations on `ProfileService` and others in order for them to be injected into the application context.

Alternatively, you can have a basic unit test without starting the whole application context where `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations would work as you expect. Just make sure to properly initialize the mocks. The easiest way would be to annotate the test class with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`